Create bimodal distribution from two uniform distribution using Numpy
I am trying to reproduce the bimodalSample function of this blog in Python.
My attempt:
import numpy as np
    
def bimodal_pdf(distance: float, weight: float) -> np.ndarray:
    r = np.random.rand()

    if r < weight:
        return np.random.normal(r) * (1 - distance)
    else:
        return np.random.normal(r) * (1 - distance) + distance


n_samples = 100000
distance = 0.7
weight = 0.5


pdf = np.array([
    bimodal_pdf(distance=distance, weight=weight) for s in range(n_samples)
])

However, I am getting values below zero and above 1. What's wrong with my implementation?
Thanks

You are using a normal distribution, which could, with low probability, produce anything from -infinity to +infinity

What you are generating is not a pdf. You have simply drawn 100000 samples from some distribution. The pdf is a "density function" of your samples (imagine it to be like a histogram). If many samples have a certain similar value, there will be a high density there.
If you want to observe your density, you can use a histogram or a kdeplot.
import seaborn as sns

samples = np.array([
    bimodal_pdf(distance=distance, weight=weight) for s in range(10000)
])
sns.kdeplot(samples)




I am getting values below zero and above 1

Just a reminder, that the PDF can be above 1. (Of course, it will never be negative). Rather, the area under the whole PDF curve is 1.

From a quick look at the blog, the post claims to generate a bimodal normal distribution from a uniform distribution, but ends up sampling from random.normal, which completely defeats the purpose.
If you are really interested in how to generate any distribution from a uniform distribution, the general method is to use the inverse of the CDF of your desired distribution. Try looking up Inverse Transform Sampling.
